# Invalid geometry objects in Shapely list

Tags: python, shapefile, geometry, geopandas, shapely

I have a creating a list of shapely polygons. While I am trying to create a geodataframe from that list it gives an error:

```
intersec_ls = [poly1, poly2, poly3]
cu = cascaded_union(intersec_ls)
differ = buffer.difference(cu)

fin_ls.append(differ)
fin_ls.append(intersec_ls)

geom = gpd.GeoSeries(fin_ls)
gdf = gdf( geometry= geom)

TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x00000213702BEDA0>]
```

How can I deal with invalid geometry in the list?

Comment: gdf has 30000 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your script.

1. Since `intersect_ls` is a list, use `extend` instead of `append`. The reason of getting error is that. Because the first item in `fin_ls` is a geometry, the other is a list, but it should have been a geometry too.

   ```
    fin_ls.append(differ)
    fin_ls.extend(intersec_ls)
   ```
2. Since `gdf` is a `GeoDataFrame` instance, you cannot use parenthesis with `gdf` as in `gdf( geometry= geom)`. Instead, use

   ```
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry=geom)
   ```

Or just use `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geom)` if you didn't define `gdf` before. In this case `gdf` includes only geometries.