# Pandas dataframe to geodataframe

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, pandas

I have pandas dataframew ith two fields: **ID** and **geometry** (geometry is already in WKT). I want to change this dataframe into geodataframe so I can save it as shapefile.

I have tried to change it into geodataframe in the followong way:

```
covex = gdf(covex, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry='geometry')
covex.to_file("covex.shp")
```

that didn't work and I got this error message:

> TypeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable

```
covex = gdf(covex, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=covex.iloc[:,1])
covex.to_file("covex.shp")
```

but I got the same error messege.

What do I do wrong? I thought I should pass the geoemtry column there but seems like it should be somethng else. how can I change this into geodataframe and then to shapefile?

Comment: can you provide more on what `gdf` function is? or how your pandas `convex` look like by giving the result of `convex.head(5)`?

Comment: Please review this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364355/29431

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a function there(gdf.**GeoDataFrame**), I'm assuming you are importing geopandas as gdf.

here is a link to the documentation for creating GeoDataFrames, although I don't see anything about using a df to create, but I can't imagine it wouldn't work
https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html
https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geodataframe

```
import geopandas as gdf

# Thish should create a new dataframe
covex = gdf.GeoDataFrame(covex, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=covex.iloc[:,1])
covex.to_file("covex.shp")
```